# Angular cli putting all component styles in head of document

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

All css for a pages components is being inserted into the head of the document.
[image]

Is there a way to bundle all these styles into a separate file which will then be referenced in the head of the document?  Similar to how bootstrap and any other external css libraries are being handled.

Comment: Are you using angular universal?

Comment: @David Yes, I think so.    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "5.0.0-beta.5", "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "5.0.0-beta.5", –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. The in-document CSS styles are inserted into the head automatically when using angular universal so that it speeds up page display. From my understanding, it's just the css needed to display the page's components as of their rendering state, it's not all of the CSS that is included.

Just having links to the CSS files would cause extra requests to be sent before displaying the page and would be slower.

Have a look here https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/868

> Where do you think this styling should go? Keep in mind that the point of SSR is to provide the output generated by the server as quickly as possible, and having an external stylesheet delays this considerably.

Answer (score 0):

Add all your CSS files in the styles.css located in /src folder like:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700');
@import 'css/exampleStyle.css';
```

And then add styles.css in your angular.json file:

```
"styles": [ "src/styles.css"]
```

Which is usually done by default.

Or you can directly mention the css files in your angular.json:

```
"styles": [ "src/css/exampleStyles.css"]
```

Add individual CSS elements in your *.component.css files

Comment: It's the individual css files - the ones in *.component.css that are being inserted into the head of the document.  Anything that is declared in the angular.json file is being bundled.   I'm concerned that if I specifically declare all the component css files in the angular.json file it will bundle that css AND include it in the head of the document